# Format content value from DB outside of WordPress filters

Tags: filters, shortcode, the-content, post-content, wp-autop

We're using WordPress to maintain data for a site that gets feed into a `JSON` file.

I've noticed that the post content we add to our file is not getting formatted appropriately. So when we feed it to our other website, the post content has no `HTML`, like paragraph tags.

I know that get_the_content runs the content through the WordPress filter to add all the correct `HTML` formatting. However, since we are making direct calls to the database in a custom script, we're just getting the raw post content.

What would we need to do in order to run our content through the WordPress content filter while our script is not connected to WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few filters and actions here that run. You'd need to look at the code and figure out what/how to utilize these.

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/unescape_invalid_shortcodes/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_shortcode_regex/