# What is the best / efficient way to get WordPress content by post id and why?

Tags: posts, content

I just wanted to get WordPress content by post id. I found the following three ways to get WordPress content by post id. (All the following ways I found on this site.)

Method 01:

```
$content_post = get_post($my_postid);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
```

Method 02:

```
$content=get_post_field('post_content', $my_postid);
```

Method 03:

```
$content=apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $my_postid));
```

What is the best / efficient  way from above there methods and why?

Comment: I'd say the way with the least amount of code, function calls, and queries. What did you do to try and profile these? What are the results of your benchmarks? Did you account for oEmbeds and Shortcode in your content - does that matter? Where are you using this data after you gather it? You should supply better context to the question for a more useful answer.

Comment: Also, I think I remember there being a few filters to run on the content - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/245057/84219

Comment: @jgraup I asked this question after writing a answer for this question (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/245661/generate-meta-name-description-using-the-page-title-first-sentence-of-body/)

Comment: as @jgraup say, this question lacks context and "best" can be decided only in a specific context for anything which is not trivial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods you offer for comparison are pretty much the same, with minor API differences and whether `the_content` filters are applied.

Within the loop `get_the_content()` should typically be used, which properly handles split into pages and so on.

To retrieve raw content `get_post_field()` is generally suitable, but any further processing (such as `the_content` filters) heavily depends on specific *purpose* of retrieving content and what you are going to do with it.

PS take note that many extensions out there are dumb and variously break on `the_content` filter executed outside of loop / more than once.